# i2c man in the middle

Tags: i2c

I'm developing a bridge, or man in the middle for touch controller and a system board connected with I2C.  The connection is:

Touch Controller(slave)---I2C---(master)STM32(slave)---I2C---(master)ARM Board

The original i2c cable is cut in half and STM32 is sitting in the middle.

The point it letting common communication through and just sometimes after an external trigger injecting a click event. (It's for automated testing.) The TC is the only I2C device on the bus.

Have someone done something similar?

The protocol is simple. The ARM board writes two bytes address.Then reads several(3-259) bytes.

I'm trying to request data from TC after receiveEvent() from master, but I don't know how many bytes shall I request. It also takes time for the answer.

Any ideas?

Comment: How is this question Arduino related? Perhaps, you are on the wrong channel. ;-) There is also a better chance of getting help if you provide some code. For me it is complete unclear how the communication TC<--> ARM is done on the protocol level. One guess: It seems the ARM initiates the communication. It sends the TC address to the bus. The ARM orders the TC to write and then provides a clock signal. The TC send the data bytes using the clock. If there is no data left it send a Stop signal.

Comment: Let the STM pass a read request from the ARM to the TC. Let the STM read data from the TC and send it to the ARM. If the data is not yet available the STM drives the clock line to LOW that pauses the ARM until there is data. If the TC sends a stop (interrupt) send a stop to the ARM too. If you have data to inject, you can inject it as long as the ARM started the communication and STM has not send the stop flag.

Comment: Possibly the only requirement is that the touch controller supports clock stretching. I think generally it's possible, but I see now specific question or code. So, have you allready tried anything?

Comment: I've tried passing SDA and SCL trough with interrupts. But the bus frequency is 340kHz and the introduced latency to high. Then I was trying requesting slave in receiveEvent() from master. It hangs the whole system I'll try the trick with driving the SCL down as Peter suggests. Or implementing part of the touch protocol. And I've ordered an I2C multiplexer as fail save solution.